# {"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I keep getting the {"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"} error. I print the json it's receiving and it seems correct
`{'order_package': {'package': 1, 'package_quantity': 1}}`

Here's all the code I think is related.

The post method:

```
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def post(self, request):
    print(request.data)
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = serializers.CartSerializer(data=data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
    else:
        return Response.status_code(500)
```

Cart model:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
  order_package = models.ForeignKey(OrderPackage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
  order_item = models.ForeignKey(OrderItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

and the order package:

```
class OrderPackage(models.Model):
  package = models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  package_quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I also tried not using json parser and passing request.data right into the data= in the serializer which gives the same error. Any help is appreciated.

Console:

```
{'order_package': {'package': 1, 'package_quantity': 1}}
Bad Request: /api/restaurants/addtocart
[17/Dec/2020 08:54:03] "POST /api/restaurants/addtocart HTTP/1.1" 400 73
```

Comment: JSON need double quotes `"` not single quotes `'`

Comment: @LucaAngioloni I tried it with double quotes too. Same error

Comment: Also: `data = JSONParser().parse(request.data)` otherwise you are not parsing the JSON but the whole request.

Comment: @LucaAngioloni that gives me AttributeError("'dict' object has no attribute 'read'")

Comment: Then `request.data` is already a dictionary. No need to parse a JSON, it's already parsed.

Comment: @LucaAngioloni right so when passing request.data directly to the serializer I still get the same error like i said in the question

Comment: @Rayyan do you mean the print(request.data) line? it returns {'order_package': {'package': 1, 'package_quantity': 1}} I have it in the question

Comment: @Yousef I'm sorry, I didn't read the question thoroughly.

Comment: @Yousef did you try: `serializer = serializers.CartSerializer(data=request.data)` directly?

Comment: @LucaAngioloni yes. Same error.

Comment: 1) where **exactly** are you getting that error?  It looks like it comes from DRF's content parsing, so how are you sending the request?  2) DRF parses the json body for you, you don't need to do anything 3) parse(request) will not work, request is an `Request` object, not a file-like object with `read()` 4) `data=request.data` is the correct way to pass to the serializer

Comment: @AndrewBacker I'm getting the error as a response. In django in just says Bad Request: /url. Also yeah still the same error when i do data=request.data

Comment: @Yousef So, how are you sending the request, and what does the RAW request look like, if possible.  This looks like an error from DRF, because the request is not valid json.  If its from somewhere else, please include the stack trace (which is in the console) in its entirety.

Comment: @AndrewBacker I added it to the questions. It prints the request.data and then the error is just bad request. Nothing helpful. No other errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have try this code just can solve your error

```
def post(self, request):
    print(request.data)
    serializer = serializers.CartSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
    else:
        return Response.status_code(500)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29131251)

Comment: @endo.anaconda OK I'm sorry. I just joined stack overflow today.